# Writing DataFrame to CSV with add header name for row names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Data frame:

```
In [18]: import pandas as pd
In [32]:  df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([("A\tbar", [1, 2, 3]), ("B\tfoo" , [4, 5, 6])],orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

In [33]: df
Out[35]: 
   one  two  three
A\tbar    1    2      3
B\tfoo    4    5      6

In [34]: df.to_csv("tmp.csv" , sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', doublequote=False)
```

The final written file looks like this (note the double quote in row name still exist too, we'd like to remove that):

```
In [34]: !cat tmp.csv
    one two three
"A  bar"    1   2   3
"B  foo"    4   5   6
```

What I want to do is to name the columns of the row names that looks like this in 
the final created file (tmp.csv):

```
alpha othername one two three
A   bar     1   2   3
B   foo     4   5   6
```

What's the way to do it?

Comment: If you want them to be separate columns, why don't you create them as separate columns instead of a single column with a tab in it?

Comment: In actual case the creation of row names is more complex that that. I'd like to keep it simple for the problem statement.

Comment: The basic answer is that you can't name the columns of your rownames, because your row names don't have columns.  Your index is just a bunch of strings that happen to have tabs in them, but pandas doesn't know that they all have tabs in them.  You could give the first column a name with a tab in it too (i.e., name it `"alpha\tothername").

Comment: If I make the `row names` as another column, how do I exclude row names from being printed out? It'll be great if you can guide with example code.

Comment: You can exclude the index by passing `index=False` to `to_csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to BrenBarn for `index=False`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([("A\tbar", [1, 2, 3]), ("B\tfoo" , [4, 5, 6])],orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
df['col_a'] = df.index
lista = [item.split('\t')[0] for item in df['col_a']]
listb = [item.split('\t')[1] for item in df['col_a']]
df['col_a'] = lista
df['col_b'] = listb
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-2:] + cols[:-2]
df = df[cols]
df.to_csv('filename', index=False)
```